# In MSBuild, how do I aggregate an ItemGroup (specifically, find the largest number in the metadata of a group?)

Tags: msbuild

I have tried using a batch target to batch by the metadata field that contains the number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <HighestNumber>0</HighestNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TextFiles Include="*.txt" />
    <TextFiles Update="*.txt">
      <Number>%(TextFiles.Filename)</Number>
    </TextFiles>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="SetUpMyStuff">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="HighestNumber: $(HighestNumber)"/>
    <CallTarget Targets="FindLargerNumber" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="HighestNumber: $(HighestNumber)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="FindLargerNumber">
    <CreateProperty Value="$([System.Math]::Max($(HighestNumber), %(TextFiles.Number)))">
      <Output PropertyName="HighestNumber" TaskParameter="ValueSetByTask" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="HighestNumber: $(HighestNumber)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Here's the diagnostic output:

```
1>  Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "Message"
1>    Task Parameter:Importance=High
1>    Task Parameter:Text=HighestNumber: 0
1>    HighestNumber: 0
1>  Done executing task "Message".
1>  Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "CallTarget"
1>    Task Parameter:Targets=FindLargerNumber
1>    Target "FindLargerNumber" in file "e:\Projects\BaseLibrary\Test.targets":
1>      Using "CreateProperty" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=0
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=0
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=1
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=1
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "0" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "1"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=10
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=10
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "1" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "10"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=2
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=2
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "10" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "2"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=3
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=3
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "2" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "3"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=4
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=4
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "3" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "4"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=5
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=5
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "4" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "5"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=6
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=6
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "5" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "6"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=7
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=7
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "6" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "7"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=8
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=8
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "7" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "8"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "CreateProperty"
1>        Task Parameter:Value=9
1>        Output Property: HighestNumber=9
1>        The property "HighestNumber" with value "8" is being overridden by another batch. The property is now: "9"
1>      Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>      Task "Message"
1>        Task Parameter:Importance=High
1>        Task Parameter:Text=HighestNumber: 9
1>        HighestNumber: 9
1>      Done executing task "Message".
1>    Done building target "FindLargerNumber" in project "BaseLibrary.csproj".
1>  Done executing task "CallTarget".
1>  Task "Message"
1>    Task Parameter:Importance=High
1>    Task Parameter:Text=HighestNumber: 0
1>    HighestNumber: 0
1>  Done executing task "Message".
```

HighestNumber isn't getting the accumulated highest number, it's getting stomped by each batched target and then it is back to 0 after all the batched targets are called.

How can I get the highest number into a property?

Comment: Are you using the latest available MSBuild version? I am wondering whether this could have been fixed by https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/1896.

Comment: You can also monitor an open MSBuild issue where I have just posted a couple of simplified repros inspired by your question:

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2249#issuecomment-342578536

Perhaps that will yield an explanation, a workaround and/or an eventual fix.

Comment: dotnet msbuild /? has this version:
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.8.50001 for .NET Core

Comment: OK, that is the latest. I will wait a while to see if anyone from Microsoft replies to my comment with those repros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild does not behave as I would have expected when we try to populate a property with the highest number using batching in conjunction with either a condition or property function (see my comments under the question for details). Given that, we can fall back to creating an inline task and using `Enumerable.Max<Int32>` in c#. Note that this implementation treats any string (e.g. file name) that can't be parsed as an `Int32` as `0`.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="GetMax" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Numbers ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />  
      <Max ParameterType="System.Int32" Output="true" />  
    </ParameterGroup>  
    <Task>  
      <Using Namespace="System.Linq"/>  
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">  
  <![CDATA[  
        if (Numbers.Length > 0)  
        {
          int number;
          Max = Numbers.Max(item => Int32.TryParse(item.ItemSpec, out number) ? number : 0);
        }  
  ]]>
      </Code>  
    </Task>  
  </UsingTask>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Number Include="*.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PopulateMaxViaInlineTask">
    <GetMax Numbers="@(Number->'%(Filename)')">  
      <Output PropertyName="Max" TaskParameter="Max" />  
    </GetMax>  
    <Message Importance="High" Text="HighestNumber: $(Max)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I just discovered InlineTask yesterday, and wanted to do exactly that, but then discovered that it doesn't work when targeting .Net Core, so I created a tiny assembly with a Task that has the equivalent code in it.

Comment: @JeremyMorton - My answer does what your question asked (your question did not mention you were targeting .Net Core). Please consider either accepting my answer or else upvoting it and submitting and accepting your own answer.